# animation of icon under nav menu

Tags: javascript, css

I have asked a few questions about this project before. I have created a mock webpage as part of a class evaluation.

You can find the page on my github here: [dtarvin.github.io/davidTarvinEvaluation/index.html](http://dtarvin.github.io/davidTarvinEvaluation/index.html)

There's a nav menu at the bottom right corner of the page. When you highlight over one of the menu items, a paw icon slides in under the menu item, and the menu item moves up vertically. Then when you move to another item, the paw slides to that next item, which moves up vertically, while the previous item moves back down to its original position.

Two problems: First, when I have the paw under an item, if I have my cursor pointer to the left or right of the paw the menu item stays raised in height. However, if my pointer is on the paw itself, the menu item returns to its original position. How do I fix this?

Second, when I move from one menu item to another, say from Home to About, the Home drops down before the paw has moved out from under it, so that the paw ends up dragging across the word Home. Is there any way to fix it so that this does not occur?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first problem is a z-index issue, the paw is on top of your text, but the hover only triggers on the text, so either apply the hover to the paw as well or move the text above the paw. Your second issue is a timing one, which I think a transition delay would fix.

Answer (score 0):

1) add the css property of `pointer-events: none;` to `#paw`.

```
#paw {
    //other properties...
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

2) add a `top` property value for `li span` when not hovered and add a transition delay.

```
li span {
    position: relative;
    transition: top .5s 0.5s; //this has a 0.5s delay
    top: -0vh;
}
```